# Can one find mean of quotient of r.v. only knowing they are uncorrelated.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ have mean $\overline{X}=10$ and $Y$ be $1$ or $2$ with equal probability. Assume $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. Can using only these assumptions 
$$E[X/Y]$$

be found? This arose from an applied course and usually the mathematics is easy, but I can't seem to make this work unless I can assume independence.
If it was just the product i could use that the covariance was 0, but I don't feel like generally transformations maintain uncorrelatedness.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What helps here is that $Y$ is such a simple variable. If it took three different values, we would not be able to determine $E[X/Y]$ from the information given. But with two this is possible. Indeed, $E[ X \mid Y=1] =   E[X\mid Y=2] = 10$ because unequal conditional expectations would make $X$ and $Y$ correlated. Hence, 
$$E[X/Y] = P[Y=1]\cdot E[ X \mid Y=1]  + P[Y=2]\cdot E[ X/2 \mid Y=2]   = \frac12 \cdot 10+\frac12 \cdot 5 = 7.5$$